# How to make content that start frorm the middle of the page to the end of the page?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
_________________
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________| <content starts>
|                |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|<content ends>
|footer          |
——————————————————
```

It should be bottom to each screen resolution...
From mobile devices to large screen.
I tried with postion:absolute but it is messed with mobile devices..

Comment: `postion:absolute` when works fine, that the parent element has `postion:relative`. but add some screen shot to understand you question fully

Comment: margin-left perhaps? -- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-left.asp

Comment: As of now i kept it as a absolute position but when i checked it in mobile devices it messed with other things. E.g if i open contact page on small screen it covered full screen and overlapped navigation..

Answer (score 3):

You could try to add a `margin-top: 50vh;` (50vh = 50% of viewport height)

if you want it to be exactly 50% of height and fixed on bottom, you can also set `height: 50vh;position: fixed;bottom: 0px;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/na3w6kav/

you can try using VH instead of % in margin-top property to find out, what fits you best, because both units have little different behavior while resizing the window. VH units are also in range 0-100.

```
<div class="halfscreentop">Text here
</div>
<div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
```

CSS:

```
.halfscreentop {position:relative; margin auto;
width:100%; background:#ccf; margin-top:50%;}

.footer{position:relative; margin auto;
width:100%; height:40px; background:#ff0;}
```

Comment: Yup thats fine but vh doesnt work with ie8.

Comment: who the hell would optimise his webpage for IE8 in theese days???

Comment: -_- there is still people on earth who are using ie8.

Comment: But thats actually their problem. IE8 was automatically upgraded via windows update on Vista and newer. Also, the graphic core of IE was (and I think I can tell that it still is) quite a mess. You wrote a page and than, you had to do lot of optimisation to get page working not only for ALL the 3rd party browser, that is ok for you already, but also for this crap. People have to be forced to use new software, especially, if it is FREE and in most of other features BETTER. Also I have to mention, that IE is 7 years old (released March 2009). So, I have to say it again - why to optimise for IE 8.